# Could Not Find Stored Procedure in SQL and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I get an error

> Could not find stored procedure 'spResetPassword'

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spResetPassword
    @eposta NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @kullaniciid INT

    SELECT 
        @kullaniciid = kullaniciid, 
        @eposta = eposta 
    FROM 
        kullanici 
    WHERE 
        eposta = @eposta

    IF(@kullaniciid IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @GUID UniqueIdentifier
        SET @GUID = NEWID()

        INSERT INTO sifresifirlamaistekleri(id, kullaniciid, sifirlamaistegitarihi) 
        VALUES(@GUID, @kullaniciid, GETDATE())

        SELECT 1 AS ReturnCode, @GUID AS UniqueId, @eposta AS eposta
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS ReturnCode, NULL AS UniqueId, NULL AS eposta
    END
END
```

And my aspx.cs code is as follows:

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aytasarimConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spResetPassword", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@eposta", TxtEPosta.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["ReturnCode"]))
        {
            SifreSifirla(rdr["eposta"].ToString(), rdr["UniqueID"].ToString());
            string mesaj = "<script>alert('Şifre sıfırlama linki e-posta adresinize gönderildi!');</script>";
            Response.Write(mesaj);
        }
        else
        {
            string mesaj = "<script>alert('Şifre sıfırlama linki e-posta adresinize gönderilirken bir sorun oluştu!');</script>";
            Response.Write(mesaj);
        }
    }
}
```

Where are my mistakes? Btw in my database, I can't find my stored procedure in `Databases > aytasarim > Programmability > Stored Procedures`. I save my procedure but why can't I see it?

Comment: What is your default schema?  If it's something other than `dbo`, you'll need to add that in your call.

Comment: I solved the problem. Amit, you're right I saved my procedure in master database by chance. Now I fix this.